# What does it mean when a message for a thrown exception is a GUID

Tags: file-upload, timer-jobs, ssom

I noticed this unexpected entry in the trace log on one of our on-premise 2013 farms:

```
85c6b8ca-b2a3-4c6e-8a9f-d60d96224577 Stack trace:   
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile.GetFileStream(OpenBinaryFlags openOptions, String etagNotMatch, String& etagNew, String& contentTagNew)    
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile.OpenBinaryStream(SPOpenBinaryOptions openOptions, String etagNotMatch, String& etagNew)    
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile.OpenBinaryStream(SPOpenBinaryOptions openOptions)
```

I also managed to find the source of the exception which is inside a custom timerjob:

```
SPFile file = null;
using (var site = new SPSite(siteCollectionUrl))
{
    file = site.RootWeb.GetFile(folderRelativeFilePath);
}
var stream = file.OpenBinaryStream(); // this call throws the above exception
```

The file type of the file in question is XSD and I have already verified that the XSD-syntax is correct. I am also able to replicate the error on my development environment but the exception is not thrown in debug mode. My question is why I am seeing a GUID instead of the message for the exception and is there any way of getting the actual message? This is a similar question to [this stackexchange question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/122557/what-does-a-guid-as-error-message-mean) but with some important differences:

- The exception is thrown from native code in `SPFile.GetFileStream` and not in any custom code.
- The GUID is not the correlation id, feature id or any other GUID in the VS Solution or trace log.

I should also mention that the code runs fine in spite of the exception being thrown.

Comment: Did you try checking in ULS log?

Comment: Have you tried a try-catch to see if the error message is more specific?

Comment: That is where the exception came from, ULS log and trace log is the same thing

Comment: Is this a result of the "throw new SPException(message);" ?

Comment: @ErinL Yes but the exception is not thrown when I debug the code. Even if I configure VS to throw all CLR exceptions it appears to be caught and handled internally

Comment: @GeorgeGrainger No I only included it because it was part of the code but I removed it now, sorry about the confusion

Comment: if you use `try{} catch(Exception ex) { [function to print to log](ex.Message) }`, you should get something more specific in your ULS trace logs.